# Вопросительный знак в ССП

Tags: пунктуация

Вот предложение -

"Но к#к 0тличNть натур#льный матер#ал 0т иск7сственн0го, #сли с0временные пр0изв0дители к к4ким тол#ко не прибег#ют ухищр3ниям, чт0бы прид#ть к0жзаму натур#льный вид".

- извините, так написала, чтобы уникальность не сбить)) надеюсь все понятно. 
  Вопросительный знак в конце предложения я не поставила, так как мне показалось, что последние предложения в составе сложноподчиненного перебивают сам вопрос, который стоит в начале. Может я не права?

Comment: А давайте я вопрос закрою, что уникальность не сбивать?!

Comment: я нарушила правила вашего сайта?

Comment: Нет, это для поддержания уникальности.

Answer (score 3):

Вопросительный знак нужно поставить. Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если вопрос содержится и в главной, и в придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, либо в придаточной.

Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д.Э.

Comment: Спасибо большое!